# Overloading "+" operator, wrong result?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I have a custom class which is designed to service a 2d array. I have overloaded the `+` operator but am getting some strange results that I didn't anticipate. I have the copy and assignment constructors here:

```
Array<T, ROW, COL>& operator=(const Array<T, ROW, COL> &rhs) {
    if (this != &rhs) {
        // allocate new memory
        T *newData = new T[ROW * COL];
        for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
                newData[j*ROW + i] = rhs(i, j);
            }
        }
        data = newData;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

and here is my overloaded `+` operator:

```
inline Array<T, ROW, COL> &operator+(const Array<T, ROW, COL> &rhs) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            this->data[j*ROW + i] += rhs(i,j);
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Here is a section of `main`:

```
Array<double, 10> ten;
ten.fill(10.0); // fill with tens
Array<double, 10> result = ten + ten + ten + ten;
std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

Yeilds:

```
[0]: 80 
[1]: 80 
[2]: 80 
[3]: 80 
[4]: 80 
[5]: 80 
[6]: 80 
[7]: 80 
[8]: 80 
[9]: 80
```

Which doesn't make sense to me. I would think that the result would be `40` all the way around. I have the copy and assignment constructors defined if ya'll need to see them.

What am I not understanding? Thanks!

Comment: You are leaking the old value of `data` in your assignment operator.

Comment: Your `operator+` is actually `operator+=`.

Comment: Just a passing comment. The test `if (this != &rhs)` isn't useful. Of course it's silly for a user to assign an object to itself, but the code without the test will work just fine when someone does this, so this test is **only** optimizing misuse.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks for the suggestion. I have been reading online how to overload operators and that test was in one of the guides, but now that I look at it, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @TylerJandreau - much of what you read online is too general or vague.

Comment: In short, your `+` overload behaves like `+=`. So after `ten + ten`, ten is filled with 20. Then another `+ ten` (`+= 20`) makes it 40, then the last `+ ten` (`+= 40`) makes it 80.

Comment: @PeteBecker actually... I don't get it.... What should the desired behaviour be if (this == rhs) ?? PS: I am pretty sure, that Tyler meant [this article](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html) with "read online"

Comment: @klyonrad Yeah that's the article.

Comment: @klyonrad - the desired behavior is that the observable behavior of the object is unchanged. Sometimes you have to look for self-assignment because it causes problems. In this case, it does some wheel-spinning, but the resulting object still hass the same values as it did before, i.e. the numbers at each location in the matrix are the same. So, as I said, looking for self-assignment in this case is optimizing a rare case that often indicates bad design.

Comment: @klyonrad - yes, that article says (in CAPITAL LETTERS) that you must always check for self assignment. That's not correct. If you write code the way that article does, you need to; if you write it differently, as this example does, there's no harm in self-assignment. And another benefit of doing it this way is that your object doesn't get blown up if the code throws an exception. Don't delete data until you know you're finished with it. That makes code much more robust in the presence of exceptions **and** protects against self assignment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't, just don't. `operator+` shouldn't modify the internal state of either of its operands. The correct prototype would be

```
Array<T, ROW, COL> operator+(Array<T, ROW, COL> lhs, const Array<T, ROW, COL> &rhs)
{
    //logic goes here
    return lhs;
}
```

As you can see, you return **by value** and modify neither of the original parameters (the first one is passed by value, but since you're creating either a copy of it or a new object inside the function to return it, passing it by value is just as good - alternatively you can pass it by `const` reference). If you must keep it as a member (the one I wrote is the free operator), prototype it as

```
Array<T, ROW, COL> Array::operator+(const Array<T, ROW, COL> &rhs) const;
```

note the `const` qualifier, which tells you (and the reader) that `this` isn't modified.

EDIT: Ok, finally found the link - **read [this](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/20/gotw-4-class-mechanics/)**

Comment: Note this suggested function is not a class member.

Comment: @aschepler which is the recommended way of doing it :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I see what I did. How very clumsy of me. Thank you for the help, it is now producing the correct result.

Comment: @TylerJandreau note that by passing the first argument by value, this is a perfect candidate for implementation in terms of `+=`. The implementation would be as simple as `return lhs += rhs;`.

Comment: One too many lines in Sutter's implementation (unless I am missing some clever subtlety) :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza: Herb's version may be more amenable to NRVO (although probably not -- sharing the return value storage with a parameter isn't likely to be possible anyway).